# Ubuntu prompt styling on WSL2 messed up after changing default user to root

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I ran `ubuntu config --default-user root` on an elevated Windows cmd, but it seems to have messed up my prompt styling:

[image: Prompt style]

Before I updated the default user, the prompt had a similar color to the directories listed by ls. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: See this: https://superuser.com/questions/268460/wheres-bashrc-for-root

Answer (score 0):

I believe Ubuntu as standard has the root prompt in b/w only.
You can change this in root's .bashrc
Find the following line in .bashrc

```
force_color_prompt=no
```

And change it to:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

Now root prompt should be in color also.